# TCP/UDP over cell network

Tags: tcp, udp, osi, cdma

I'm a novice in this area looking for clarification.  I believe that CDMA would be classified as part of the physical layer, so what is used for the data link layer (according to the OSI model) in cellular networks?  Is TCP/UDP used in cellular networks?  If so, in what capacity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a CDMA network (and some others, such as GPRS and HSPA), PPP is used at the Data Link Layer (layer 2).

TCP/UDP (or more generally, IP) is indeed used in CDMA networks to mostly for connection to the CMDA providers ISP network for Internet access by phones and "data sticks".

These data sticks usually provide an emulated modem on a serial port over USB, which is used in a very similar manner to dial-up modems of days gone by. You'd use the same "AT commands" to establish a connection, the only difference being the relatively high speed of the emulated serial port.